# Animate background gradient using styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, material-ui, styled-components

I'm setting the background of the `<Paper />` (I'm using Material-UI, v1.0.0-beta.25) as a gradient of colors. The colors are added automatically by clicking the Add button and choosing one from the color picker. By this time, my code does this:

[image]

I want to animate the background gradient of the component to get something like [this](https://codepen.io/P1N2O/pen/pyBNzX). Using the code of the pen, removing some lines that I considered unnecessary and adding the implementation of `styled-components`, I wrote:

```
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

{/* rest of the code */}

render() {

  const gradient = keyframes`
    0% {
      background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
      background-position: 100% 50%
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 0% 50%
    }
  `;

  const MyPaper = styled(Paper)`
    && {
      background: ${ colors.length == 0 ? `linear-gradient(to right, ${ "#FFFFFF" }, ${ "#FFFFFF" })` 
        : `linear-gradient(to right, ${ colors.map((color, key) => color.name ) })` };

      animation: ${gradient} 15s ease infinite;
    }
  `;

  return (
    <div>
      <div className = { classes.root }>

        {/* Color selected */}
        <div>
          <MyPaper className = { classes.paperStyle } elevation = { 4 }></MyPaper>
        </div>
        <br /><br /><br />

        {/* rest of the code */}
```

but for some reason the background doesn't get animate.

Am I doing something wrong, missing something, or is there another way to do that? I'll appreciate any help to achieve my goal. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the structure of your array `colors`?

Comment: @Dez `state = { colors : [], };` and this is the [method](https://gist.github.com/ArCiGo/e1202d8d249aef0948249fa03b74dcd5), by this time, that stores the colors in the array

Comment: Would you mind sharing this component?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the structure of your array `colors` that I am not sure if it is right, you need to define in the CSS for your component `MyPaper` a background-size value greater than 100% and 100% in order to the animation to work.

```css
@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
      background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
      background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
      background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}

.gradient {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow, blue);
 background-size: 110% 110%;
 animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

.cool {
 background: linear-gradient(to right, green, red, black);
 background-size: 200% 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
<div class="gradient cool"></div>
```

Maybe you might need to set a size (height and width) to your `Paper` component of Material in order to make it work too.

Comment: Thanks, man. That solved my problem. I added the `background-size` in my [component](https://gist.github.com/ArCiGo/053b0cab7cf653ba235aaac9e1a66144). Is there a way to animate the background like a loop? I don't want a sway movement

Comment: Set a timer with the same duration of the animation and use a function inside it that swaps the order of the colors in the array.